# C# MySQL connection thread-safe

Tags: c#, mysql, thread

Tenho um servidor que recebe centenas de conexões assíncronas e preciso implementar acesso ao MySQL de diferentes threads. Na verdade, como utilizo o padrão Async Socket Begin/End do .Net, existe um pool de threads, portanto não é 1 thread para cada conexão e mesmo que fosse, não iria criar 1 conexão MySQL para cada threads, isso só seria valido se fossem no máximo 10 conexões, sendo 1 conexão MySQL para cada socket conectado.

Como implemento isso? Poderiam me sugerir alguns links para estudo? Preciso utilizar algum "designe pattern" onde eu tenha um pool de conexões MySQL thread-safe, no qual mantem x conexões ativas e libere conforme a necessidade das requisições? Algo como:

```
Connection myConnection = GetSomeConnection(); // Returns a shared object
Command cmd;

lock(myConnection)
{
    cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
}
```

Comment: Não seria o caso de implementar um *singleton* no papel de *broker* - gerenciando uma fila de requisições, por exemplo? Esse é um modelo geralmente utilizado para controle de requisições a recursos únicos e compartilhados.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que um connection pool seria uma boa idéia. Uma sugestão para implementar isso (deve ter diversas outras respostas para esse problema), seria criar uma classe que gerencie as conexões e esta internamente utilizar uma ConcurrentQueue (http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx), contendo os próprios objetos de conexão.

O método que pega as conexões poderia ficar num loop "enquanto não tem conexões, thread.Sleep". A hora que encontrar uma, pega a conexão.

Ao terminar a thread, devolve a conexão utilizada para a queue. Dessa forma evita-se que haja bloqueio entre as threads (nenhum tipo de lock é utilizado).